# How to create multi-row subheader bar in ionic?

Tags: css, sass, ionic-framework

I am using the meteor ionic framework. I have no trouble creating a single row in my subheader bar.

```
+ionSubheaderBar
  input(type="search" placeholder="Search users")
```

However, I want to have several rows on my ion subheader.

```
+ionSubheaderBar
  +ionList class="card"
    +ionItem iconLeft=true
      +ionIcon icon="ios-search"
      | Item 1
    +ionItem
      | Item 2
```

However, this never seems to appropriately work. Is there a way to include an ionlist in a subheader with multiple ionitems?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Sass.